# about jQuery - image gallery

Tags: jquery, loops

```
$("#right").click(function(){
    var nextIndex=currIndex.next();

    var nextImg = nextIndex.children("img").attr("src");
    $("#main").attr("src",nextImg);

    currIndex = nextIndex;

}); 

$("#left").click(function(){
    var prevIndex=currIndex.prev();

    var prevImg = prevIndex.children("img").attr("src");
    $("#main").attr("src",prevImg);

    currIndex = prevIndex;

});
```

When I'm in the last image, the right or left arrow doesn't work.

Comment: Define "doesn't work".  What *does* it do?  When you debug this, where/how specifically does it fail?

Comment: I can clearly use left and right arrow when I start on the first image when I'm in last image then I click the right arrow again... Then the left arrow doesn't work.

Comment: "Doesn't work" isn't a description of a problem.  Try to understand what we can't see your screen from here.  No matter how hard you point at your screen to indicate where you see a problem, we're not actually in the room with you and can't see it.

Comment: You can certainly try.

Comment: Hmm Can I post here the whole prog?

Comment: If the whole program is relevant to the problem, sure.  Otherwise it would likely just add more noise than helpful information.  If the code posted is sufficient to explain the problem, I'd recommend leaving it as it is.  If more code is needed to explain the problem, go ahead and add it.  Either way, you should focus on actually explaining the problem.  This may be a great opportunity to familiarize yourself with the use of debugging tools.  You can set breakpoints in the code, pause the code while it executes, examine runtime values and behaviors, etc.

Comment: I will try to visualize it

Comment: left arrow - < Image1 > - right arrow... When I click right arrow It will go to image 2 and so on... until in the last image... Image 8 ... When I click again the right arrow I want it to go back on image 1 but it doesn't... What is the right the code I will put?

Comment: Sorry, but you seem to be missing the point of how Stack Overflow works.  We can help you with technical issues, but if you're just looking to describe functionality to someone and have that person write the code for you then what you're looking for is to hire a programmer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're getting an error because the variable is undefined, I would recommend you to check whether or not the next or previous elements exist.

```
$("#right").click(function(){ 
  var nextIndex = currIndex.next();
  if (typeof nextIndex !== "undefined") {
    var nextImg = nextIndex.children("img").attr("src");
    $("#main").attr("src",nextImg);

    currIndex = nextIndex;
  }


}); 

$("#left").click(function(){
  var prevIndex=currIndex.prev();
  if (typeof prevIndex !== "undefined") {
    var prevImg = prevIndex.children("img").attr("src");
    $("#main").attr("src",prevImg);

    currIndex = prevIndex;
  }

});
```